# Click when Ok button is clickable in Imacros?

Tags: click, imacros

I have script Imacros which is used to upload videos files. I set "wait seconds = 600" and then click Ok button. However, sometime, it only take 100 seconds or 200 seconds to upload video files. So, it is waste of times to wait more 400 seconds.

If video files wasn't uploaded completely, Ok button will NOT be show:

```
<div tabindex="0" aria-disabled="TRUE" guidedhelpid="ghid-psc" id="picker:ap:0" style="-moz-user-select: none;" role="button" class="a-b-c d-u d-u-F Ed-tb-re-enabled">Ok</div>
```

If video files wasn uploaded completely, Ok button will be show:

```
<div tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" guidedhelpid="ghid-psc" id="picker:ap:0" style="-moz-user-select: none;" role="button" class="a-b-c d-u d-u-F Ed-tb-re-enabled">Ok</div>
```

So, I want to ask: How to know video files was uploaded completely or not then click OK button ?

Thank you very much ! Sorry for my poor English !

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for.

```
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 600
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:"a-b-c d-u d-u-F Ed-tb-re-enabled"
```

When this button appears the script will click it and move on.